# Get ID of element in jQuery autocomplete source function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webservice method that takes the id of an element to determine the source for autocompletes.

In a nutshell, I'm doing this:

```
$("input[type='text']").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var params = {'id': id, 'term': request.term};
        var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(params);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Page.aspx/GetAutoCompleteList",
            data: jsonParams,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                response(JSON.parse(msg.d));
            },
            error: function() {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But `id` isn't referring to the original selector.

What can I do to get the id of the selected `input` element? Or what is a better strategy for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(this.element).prop("id");

this.element[0].id;

$(this.element.get(0)).attr('id');
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2qmre9rv/6/)

```js
$("input[type='text']").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var id = $(this.element).prop("id");
        var id2=this.element[0].id;
        var id3=$(this.element.get(0)).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        console.log(id2);
        console.log(id3);
        var params = {'id': id, 'term': request.term};
        var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(params);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Page.aspx/GetAutoCompleteList",
            data: jsonParams,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                response(JSON.parse(msg.d));
            },
            error: function() {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="asd"></input>
```

Comment: The reference of `this` in OP's problem is not going to work with the code you've provided.

Comment: What are you talking about? Check the Jsfiddle. Outputting it to the console works on all 3 examples. Also added a snippet.

Comment: OK, have yet to *really* understand what `this` will actually refer to in JS. Any pointers on a reference? What does `this` refer to in the `source` function I posted?

Comment: In your example `this` refers to the widget instance, because JqueryUI creates a widget on your selector. `this` generally refers to the curent context or selector. You have nice explanations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) but you'll get it with experience, too.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to maintain a context of each input element, something like this:

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function (i, ele) {
    ele = $(ele);
    ele.autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var id = ele.attr('id');
            var params = {'id': id, 'term': request.term};
            var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(params);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Page.aspx/GetAutoCompleteList",
                data: jsonParams,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    // ...
                },
                error: function () {
                    // ...
                },
                async: false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: should `ele` be a global variable?

Comment: `ele` is not global, it is passed into the anonymous function